# How to implement working web server with Mono WebAPI application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, mono, mod-mono, fastcgi-mono-server

Mono 3.2 MVC4 WebAPI application is running in Debian x64 VPS server. Mono is compiled from source and 4.5 subtree is used.
Application requires Chrome or Safari browser.

After refreshing browser window several times server does not work properly. I tried all known free possibilites:

**Apache + mod_mono**

After pressing browser refresh button several times server randomly returns 500 error for some pages
and apache error log contains "failed to map path" exception.

I posted it in

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356779/how-to-fix-failed-to-map-path-errors-in-mono-mvc4-application

and in

Mono ASP.NET mailing list without any response.

There are number of mono applications in server, maybe mod_mono selects wrong thread or is there some bug in webapi mapping implementation in mono.

**Nginx + mono-fastcgi-server4.exe**

Holding down F5 key causes 200% CPU usage forever in  mono-fastcgi-server4.exe

I posted it in

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512978/how-to-limit-mono-197-cpu-usage-in-mono-fastcgi-server

and in

Mono ASP.NET mailing list without any solution.

Is looks like there is bug in mono fastcgi server or it is not compatible with mono 3.2

**Using xsp4.exe directly**

It causes "server does not return data" in Chrome if browser window is refreshed several times.

I posted this in

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=329311

without response.

Maybe xsp4 does not implement http protocol properly.

Havent tried ServiceStack since it cannot used for closed source development which is required. Also application uses also images, css, js files and MVC views which needs also served.

How to create proper server for mono which returns correct data ?

Comment: ServiceStack is free according to the FSF

Comment: According to servicestack.net/pricing free is only very limited version. About failed to map path error maybe it is possible to solve it easily. I found probably line in mono source code causing this. How to get addtional information about it cause, mono does not write additional information when it throws this exception?

Comment: limited version in regards to support! there are no more features in the paying version, but you cannot use the free version if your software is not opensource. I think you don't understand the AGPL licence.

Comment: I need server for closed source development, so it looks like I cannotu use ServiceStack freely

Comment: then don't say `freely`, say `closely`. Freeness of software is about the user, not about the developer.

Comment: I updated question and replaced free with closed source. I also updaded queistion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356779/how-to-fix-failed-to-map-path-errors-in-mono-mvc4-application and added link to mono source line which probably throws the exception. How to fix this ? Should I modify this line so that also application path against which mapping fails is also printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When 500 errors happen, somewhere in the mono class libraries an exception was thrown, you can find out more by using tracing:

```
mono --trace=E:System.Exception YourApp.exe
```

This way it's very possible that you find out what is causing the load problems you're seeing in each case (to do this for mono-fastcgi, you would need to add the trace argument in the script that calls mono-fastcgi-server4.exe).

Comment: In case of Failed to map path exception apache error.log contains stack trace which I published in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356779/how-to-fix-failed-to-map-path-errors-in-mono-mvc4-application . Stack trace points probably to line 1565 in https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/mono-3.2.1-branch/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpRequest.cs#L1565  It occurs before application code is executed. What additional information will --trace provide to solve this ? How to fix it or get more information about the cause ? After several browser refresh it occurs always in diffent calls.

Comment: Great! You're getting closer to fix the problem. Now it is a matter of figuring out why that exception is not thrown under low load, and why it is thrown under heavy load. Maybe a race condition somewhere that is exposed by the heavy load? you need to examine that HttpRequest class very closely

Comment: There are several MVC4 applications running in this server. Maybe mod_mono or mod_mono_server passes request to wrong thread. Load is not heavy: after browser refresh I will wait for all calls to complete and look into Chrome console. If console is empty, this is reapeated. After some refreshes 500 error in chrome console and this exception in apache error log always occurs. It does not occur in application home page which do not contain ajax calls.

Comment: I commented those lines out (github history shows that those lines are added some time ago) and compiled 3.2.5 . This fixes seems to fix the issue. I use mod_mono from 2.6 . Should I re-compile mod_mono also ?

Comment: please submit your change as a pull request

Comment: This check looks reasonable, maybe there is some other issue, e.q. passed url is slightly different form. Bettoer is to add application base url or other logging to this message to get more information. Or maybe 3.10.5 has fixed this in some other place, previously tested 3.10.2 . So I*m not sure about this change in production. mono-Fastcgi-server4 causes also bad gateway errors randomly in addition to high CPU. It looks that is is not developed anymore, so maybe it it not worth to try fastcgi

Comment: what is 3.10.5 and 3.10.2? I don't understand those version numbers

Comment: not developed anymore? have you seen the huge activity that it had this summer? @minibill was a GSoC student revamping it, and he has done a really good job

Comment: Correct values are 3.2.1 and 3.2.5 Those are Mono version numbers. xsp package does not generate exe files for mono 4.5 subtree. Last fastcgi report from developer is 6 year old (http://kerrick.wordpress.com/category/summer-of-code-2007/)

Comment: nope, this is the last commit from the last gsoc student: https://github.com/mono/xsp/commit/b42080a0281f81ff92edd49fba8549c7aee618fe